# Booting raspberry pi 3 model b (not b+) out of the box without SD card

Tags: pi-3, raspberry-pi-os

My raspberry pi 3 B's sd card slot broke. Is there a way to boot it using USB or Ethernet? Are there any settings I can apply to a fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS on a USB drive? The board's version is 1.3

Comment: Did you happen to activate [USB host boot mode](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/host.md)?

Comment: @FelixJN no but I can try doing that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a Catch-22 if your SD reader is broken.

The usual (or only) way to modify the OTP memory's host boot mode bit is to set it via reboot of a freshly-updated Pi 3 that has had the line:
program_usb_boot_mode=1
added to /boot/config.txt

The reboot would have to be from SD.  After reboot you can check the status of the bit using the term window:
pi@raspberrypi:~$ vcgencmd otp_dump|grep 17:
17:3020000a

The bit is set, specifically first byte 0b..1._....
You might be lucky and for some reason have it already set (assuming that your Pi is currently running).  Then all you'd need is a fresh update.

With that setting, you should be able to boot from USB.  There are a number of YouTube tutorials on this topic, e.g., Christopher Barnatt's ExplainingComputers.com